# Bounding the absolute sum of entries of the inverse of a  0-1 matrix

Tags: matrices, inequalities

I have a non-singular square 0-1 matrix and I want to bound the sum of absolute values of its inverse as a function of n (or the vector 1-norm).
Asymptotic results are also useful.

Does anyone know any result that can help me?

Thank you,
ifog

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The entries can grow at least exponentially.  Let $T_n$ be the $n \times n$ matrix with ones on the main diagonal and first and third upper off-diagonals, and zeros elsewhere.  Then $T_n$  is upper triangular of determinant $1$, but its inverse has top row $1, -1, 1, -2, 3, -4, 6, -9, 13, -19, 28, -41, \ldots$ whose absolute values satisfy the recurrence $t_m = t_{m-1}+t_{m-3}$ so the $n$-th one is asymptotically proportional to $C^n$ for some constant $C>1$ (namely $1.46557\ldots$, the real root of $C^3 = C^2 + 1$).

Since $T_n$ is sparse, the entries of $T_n^{-1}$ can grow no faster than exponentially, as is seen by expressing them as $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ determinants (Cramer's rule) and applying Hadamard's inequality.  Thus for sparse matrices $C^n$ is best possible but for the size of $C$.  For a general $n \times n$ matrix with 0-1 entries and nonzero determinant, the same method gives an upper bound of $n^{(n-1)/2}$.  I do not know whether the entries can actually grow faster than exponentially, i.e. faster than $C^n$ for any fixed $C$, but would not be too surprised if that's possible.

**gp** code for $n=12$:

```
T(n) = matrix(n,n,i,j, (j==i) || (j==i+1) || (j==i+3))
T12 = T(12)
1/T12
```

returns

```
[1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

for T12 and

```
[1 -1 1 -2 3 -4 6 -9 13 -19 28 -41]
[0 1 -1 1 -2 3 -4 6 -9 13 -19 28]
[0 0 1 -1 1 -2 3 -4 6 -9 13 -19]
[0 0 0 1 -1 1 -2 3 -4 6 -9 13]
[0 0 0 0 1 -1 1 -2 3 -4 6 -9]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 1 -2 3 -4 6]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 1 -2 3 -4]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 1 -2 3]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 1 -2]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

for its inverse.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot!
I do wonder if the true C is n, maybe there's some pathological matrix showing it, but the difference between n^n and c^n is less important to me.

Comment: You're welcome.  The Cramer/Hadamard argument shows $C$ cannot reach $n$, but does allow $C$ as large as $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I define a sequence of 0-1 matrices at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11885/nontrivial-question-about-fibonacci-numbers/11902#11902 , whose determinants grow like the Fibonacci.  I suspect the inverse will have a large sum of absolute values of entries, and I suspect it will be hard to find a sequence that will beat it under this measure infinitely often.  Related: I am looking for matrices with medium determinant which are a common minor to a set of augmented matrices whose absolute determinant values form a large interval.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.22

Comment: I will stick my neck out and say exponential growth is the worst that can be expected.  Although it may require transforming to -1,1 matrices, I base my suspicion on the process of computing inverse by transforming the system A I to I B by elementary row operations.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.22

Comment: I reviewed my notes and saw where I had asked too much of the inverse of the matrices defined in a comment of mine above.  The norm of their inverses grows roughly linearly, about n times phi is my estimate.  I still stick my neck out, and suspect Noam Elkies's example will be a record holder for a while.  Gerhard "Acts Before Speaking Next Time" Paseman,  2011.11.23

Answer (score 15):

An answer is given in:

N. Alon and V. H. Vu, Anti-Hadamard matrices, coin weighing,
threshold gates and indecomposable hypergraphs, J. Combinatorial
Theory, Ser. A 79 (1997), 133-160.

Indeed C above is essentially sqrt n

Comment: (belated) Welcome to MO, Noga!

Comment: Incredible paper!

Answer (score 14):

If one is interested in the typical answer (when the matrix is a random 0-1 matrix) rather than the worst-case answer, then the inverse behaves a lot better than exponential.  Indeed, in view of the results of [Rudelson and Vershynin](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3956), it is likely that the j^th smallest singular value of the matrix has typical size $j/\sqrt{n}$.  (Technically, the Rudelson-Vershynin result doesn't directly apply because the matrix is not normalised to have mean zero, but it is likely that the conclusions of that paper also apply to the off-centered case, after removing the exceptional outlier singular value of size about n/2.)  Since the Frobenius norm of the inverse is the sum of negative second powers of the singular values, this Frobenius norm should then be about $O(n^{1/2})$, which implies by Cauchy-Schwarz that the $\ell^1$ norm of the inverse should be about $O(n^{3/2})$ typically.   (Roughly speaking, this suggests that individual entries have size $O(n^{-1/2})$, a finding which is consistent with Cramer's rule and the limiting law for the determinant of a random 0-1 matrix (which has value about $\sqrt{(n-1)!}$ on the average, see e.g. [this paper of myself and Van Vu](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411095)).

Comment: Interesting.  Unlike the extremal behavior, the "typical" 0-1's inverse could be probed for moderately large $n$ by Monte Carlo techniques $-$ what kind of experiment might corroborate your expectation?$$ $$

For the worst-case behavior, since the minors can grow faster than exponential one expects to get as large as $2^n$ or so by just choosing all but one row randomly and then trying all $2^n$ possibilities for the remaining row to find  the one that minimizes the determinant without killing it.  But that's still exponential; do you think one might get $C_n^n$ with $C_n \rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: I would believe so, but this may be out of reach of current technology.  By gaussian elimination, the determinant must be an integer multiple of $2^{n-1}$, but is believed to be otherwise unconstrained (at least for values $\ll \sqrt{(n-1)!}$).  As such, if one randomly selects $n-1$ rows, then one would expect to beat $2^n$ by a factor of $K$ with probability about $1/K$ for any given $K$, assuming there is enough of a "central limit theorem" that the random sums look Gaussian.  As there are $2^{n(n-1)}$ possible values for these rows, this suggests a substantial improvement over exponential.

Comment: Looks like you're thinking of {$-1,1$} matrices, not {$0,1$}, but I guess you expect the same thing (without the $2^{n-1}$ complication).

Comment: The spectrum (set of absolute determinant values) of order n -1,1 matrices was conjectured to achieve all multiples of 2^(n-1) below the Hadamard bound back in the '50's or '60's; this conjecture was shown false by Metropolis, Craigen, and others.  Will Orrick has the best writeup on the spectrum topic that I have seen; there are plenty of unanswered questions.  Orrick's maxdet website is a good starting point.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Determinant Spectrum" Paseman, 2011.11.22

Answer (score 6):

**Summary** The answer below mentions a conjectured **lower bound** on the Frobenius norm of the inverse of a (0-1)-matrix. I have removed the now irrelevant simple observations that were based on matrices with real entries in $[0,1]$. Exponential upper bounds are discussed in Noam's and David's answers. The average case is described by Terry.

---

As far as I know, proving the following lower bound
$$\|A^{-1}\|_F \ge \frac{2n}{n+1},$$
is still an **open problem**. Further, the conjecture states that this lower bound is achieved iff and only if $A$ is an *S-matrix* (which is a (0-1)-matrix). See [Problem 7 in this handout for more details](http://math.ecnu.edu.cn/~zhan/HangzhouZhan_beamerhandout.pdf).

Comment: When I said 0-1 I meant values that are only 0 or 1 (binary matrix, but not over Z2). I know that in this case there's a nice bound for the determinant for example. The upper bound is what interests me more.

Answer (score 6):

An observation: As long as we stick to upper triangular matrices, as in Noam's answer, we can't get growth faster than $2^n$. More precisely, let $a_{ij}$ be an upper triangular $01$ matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal and let $b_{ij}$ be the inverse matrix. Then I claim that $|b_{i(i+k)}| \leq 2^{k-1}$ for all $k>0$.

Proof: Induction on $k$. The case $k=1$ is easy because $b_{i(i+1)} = - a_{i(i+1)}$. In general,
$$\sum_{r=0}^k b_{i(i+r)} a_{(i+r)(i+k)} =0$$
so
$$|b_{i(i+k)}| = \left| \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} b_{i(i+r)} a_{(i+r)(i+k)} \right| \leq  \sum_{r=0}^{k-1} |b_{i(i+r)}|.$$
By induction, the last is bounded by $1+1+2+4+\cdots+2^{k-2} = 2^{k-1}$, and we are done.

Comment: I noticed this bound too; it applies for any upper triangular matrix with unit diagonal and off-diagonal elements of absolute value at most $1$.  But to attain equality you need $-1$ entries once $k>1$.  If only nonnegative entries are allowed then the best I can do is Fibonacci numbers.