# bounding the sum of the entries of the inverse of a 0-1 matrix away from 1?

Tags: matrix-analysis, co.combinatorics

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an invertible 0-1 matrix. Is it possible that the sum $a:=\sum_{i,j}(A^{-1})_{ij}$ of entries of $A^{-1}$ is not equal to 1, but exponentially close (w.r.t. $n$) to 1?

More precisely, the *conjecture* is that if $a\geq 1$ then either $a=1$ or $|a|\geq 1+p(n)/q(n)$, for $p$ and $q$ fixed polynomials (some other not too fast growing functions might do, too).

**Remark.** The condition $a\geq 1$ is not redundant, as there exist matrices $A$ with $a&lt;1$, e.g. $$A=\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \&bsol;
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \&bsol;
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \&bsol;
1 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right), \quad A^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \&bsol;
-1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \&bsol;
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \&bsol;
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right), \quad a=\sum_{i,j} (A^{-1})_{ij}=0.
$$

An (admittedly very shaky) evidence for this is that it is true if the row sums $r_i$ of $A$ are all equal to each other. Indeed, let $\overline 1$ denote the all-1 vector. Then $a=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ for $x$ satisfying $Ax=\overline 1$, and 
$$
\overline{1}^\top Ax=\sum_i r_i x_i=\overline{1}^\top \overline{1}=n,\quad \text{implying }\quad a\geq \frac{n}{n-1} 
$$

Comment: Thank you for the example. In return, J - I (rotated) will give an a value of n/n-1.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Binary Matrices" Paseman, 2012.12.01

Comment: more generally, one can take block $2k\times 2k$ matrix of form $\binom{I\ B}{0\ I}$, where $B$ is all-1 $k\times k$ block. Then the sum of the entries of its inverse is $-k^2+2k$.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this question had already been answered in the negative [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81496/bounding-the-absolute-sum-of-entries-of-the-inverse-of-a-0-1-matrix/81498#81498).

Comment: My reading of the linked post is that the lower bound has been conjectured as close to 2, which is supported by looking at some order 2^k - 1 matrices.  However, this poster has not made it clear if the target sum is near 1 or near n.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.30

Comment: But Noam Elkies has shown a matrix which achieves exponential sum - which disproves both readings of the conjecture.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Elkies shows that it is possible that $a$ is exponentially **big**. I am asking whether $a-1$ can be positive, but exponentially **small**.

Comment: But the conjecture is that a is always 1 or large. Noam has provided evidence for the poster's conjecture, but says not enough about how "small" large is.  I read the poster's question as what is the closest to 1 (or n) a can become without reaching that value.  Gerhard "Ask  Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.30

Comment: I can come up with examples (using k rows that add up to a row of all ones) that achieve k for any integer k from 1 to n. I imagine that one can try using row echelon manipulations to bound a away from 1.  I suggest doing some small trials (of order up to 6 at least) to get some numerical evidence for what Suvrit suggested, that 2n/(n-1) is the bound you seek.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.30

Comment: @Gerhard, more precisely, the conjecture does not say that always $a\geq 1$. It only says that **if** $a\geq$ then... 

Comment: Suvrit's suggestion is about the Frobenius norm. The conjecture he states there does not imply mine: indeed, $A^{-1}$ can have negative entries.

Comment: Dima, can you show me a 0 1 matrix with inverse whose entries sum to less than 1?  Gerhard "Pretend I Am From Missouri" Paseman, 2012.11.30

Comment: Also, why is the sum asked for near 1 in the title, and near n in the first paragraph? Gerhard "Or Is It Just Me" Paseman, 2012.11.30

Comment: Oops, typos, sorry. Must be 1s everywhere.

Comment: corrected in the question text. Regarding "0 1 matrix with inverse whose entries sum to less than 1" - I don't know.

Comment: @Gerhard, I found you a matrix you asked for, see Remark in the updated question.